Playwright Post request giving Error: apiRequestContext.post: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND intermitently
I am running into an issue where in Playwright I am getting this error every 15 or so requests
Error: apiRequestContext.post: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
for the URL I am using an  https:// development server endpoint.  The same exact request can pass and then fail, and when I debug the tests they are always passing.  Here is a helper function where it is running the post that is throwing the error:
public static async postJSONX_Access(request: APIRequestContext, endpoint: string,body: object, xAccessToken: string | undefined ) : Promise<any> 
{
        const response = await request.post(endpoint, {
            data:body,
            headers: {
            'X-Access-Token' : xAccessToken!
            },
        });
        expect(response.ok());
        return await response.json();
    }

Full error log here:
Error: apiRequestContext.post: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND d-api.company.com
Call log:

→ POST d-api.company.com/post/data
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.6533.17 Safari/537.36
accept: /
accept-encoding: gzip,deflate,br
X-Access-Token: tokenGoesHere
content-type: application/json
content-length: 2

I am testing two APIs and only running into this issue on one of them.  Any help would be appreciated, I tried the solution from this question API GET Request test using Playwright on adding
import dns from "dns"; dns.setDefaultResultOrder("ipv4first");
To my playwright.config.js folder and it didn't work to resolve the issue.
I am expecting what happens most of the time where the POST request goes through and the response is returned.  I have tried removing https:// from the baseURL, I have tried adding
import dns from "dns"; dns.setDefaultResultOrder("ipv4first");
To the config file, I have tried running ipconfig /flushdns.  When I restart my computer it is working to pass all the tests but over time these failures start popping up.

What site is this? Please share a runnable [mcve] I can execute to see the failure. If it's not public, please share a simple server that I can run with an endpoint that I can hit to repro the issue, or a public site that does reproduce the problem. Without that, there's not much to offer since the request code here is totally normal/fine.

The API is for our development environment and needs a VPN to access so you can't try hitting the same endpoint.  But if you try to hit it with Postman, or even Playwright while debugging it works every time and returns the response.

I don't see what difference it'd make doing it this way. I don't think there's a bug in Playwright specifically that says if (Math.random() * 15 < 1) { makeRequestFail() }. It should work exactly like anything else, unless your requests are different somehow, or there's an issue in the endpoint. A request is a request. So yeah, more info is needed to make this reproducible.

Okay well thanks for taking a look, when googling I have seen that Node js has had bugs related to this before and thought maybe someone else has ran into this.  But as it only happens with one of my APIs and only intermittently and the same request can pass then fail back to back I see how it is hard to give any help.

The likelihood that it's a bug in Node is extremely low, and if it is, without a [mcve], there's no way to gain traction on it or get anyone to believe it. Regardless of the issue, without a code snippet someone other than you can execute and see fail every 15 times or so, there's no way to take action here.
